# Allocating memory for triple pointer: C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to allocate memory for a triple pointer. I have the following:

```
int i, j;
int n = 4;

int ***X = (int ***) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
      printf("h\n");
      X[i] = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
      for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("j\n");
            X[i][j] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
      }
}

X[0][0][0] = 14;
X[1][2][2] = 15;
```

When I run this on Linux, I get `*** glibc detected *** triplePointer: double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000000ea3050 ***` error which I have completely no idea what it is implying. But when I run it on Windows with the -Wall flag, I get no errors. Can someone perhaps help me to find where my error is at.

Also, I am currently hard coding by having the statement `X[0][0][0] = 14;`. Is there a way that I can populate all the slots of this triple pointer by some random values?

Comment: Each of your `sizeof()` arguments is incorrect except the most inner. And I suspect when run under windows you're compiling as 32-bit, which has identical sizes for `int` and arbitrary data pointers. Compile it as a 64-bit process and you'll potentially see similar behavior as your Linux distro.

Comment: Of course! I can't believe I missed that. Ahh....

Comment: @user3754974 [This will clear your all doubts](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following code-

```
int ***X = (int ***) malloc(sizeof(int**) * n); //FIX 1
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
  printf("h\n");
  X[i] = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);  // FIX 2
  for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
        printf("j\n");
        X[i][j] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
  }
}
```

When you are allocating memory for Triple pointer first you need to allocate memory `n` double pointers.

```
int ***X = (int ***) malloc(sizeof(int**) * n); // Not sizeof(int)
```

Then for that double pointer you need to allocate memory for `n` single pointers

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  X[i] = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
```

For that single pointers you need to allocate memory finally

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
 for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        X[i][j] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

This is the way of allocation!

---

Though a bit more work, it is arguably more straight-forward to use the size of the target pointer *dereferenced* than coding the type in the `sizeof()` operator. See below, [including the advised removal of `malloc()` casts in C programs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

```
int ***X = malloc(sizeof(*X) * n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("h\n");
    X[i] = malloc(sizeof(*(X[i])) * n);
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("j\n");
        X[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(*(X[i][j])) * n);
    }
}
```

Note the only place you see an actual *type* in this is `int ***X`. Everything else is based on that initial declaration. Why is this arguably "better"? Ex: To change this entire thing to a 3D matrix of `double` would require changing *one line*: `double ***X = ...`

Comment: This code does fix the issue, but it would be a good idea to explain why it does.